# Can Green's theorem be used in a plane other than the xy-plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

In the following 2D case, Green's theorem solves the following problem:

$$\vec{F}=\langle{xy+\ln{(\sin{e^{x})},x^2+e^{y^2}}}\rangle$$

$$\oint_C\vec{F}\cdot{d\vec{r}}=\iint_Dx\space{dA}$$

where C is the unit circle $x^2+y^2=1$, and D is the unit disk $x^2+y^2\le{1}$.

But what if instead the problem were:

$$\vec{F}=\langle{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(xy+\ln{(\sin{e^x}}),x^2+e^{y^2},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(xy+\ln{(\sin{e^x}})}\rangle$$

$$\oint_C\vec{F}\cdot{d\vec{r}}$$

And $C$ is instead the unit circle $\vec{r}(t)=\langle{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos{t},\sin{t},-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos{t}}\rangle$.

This is the same problem as the first one, but rotated 45 degrees about the y-axis. I know I could solve the second problem by simply rotating the path and the vector field back 45 degrees. But is there any way to apply Green's theorem to the second problem directly?

Comment: Are you trying to generalize Green's theorem to higher dimensions?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal not exactly, because I'm still trying to find a line integral, and the path and vector field still lie within a plane. It's just a different plane than the xy-plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Green's theorem is just a special case of Stokes' theorem (which is just a special case of the *generalized* Stokes' theorem).

$$\oint_{\partial M} d\ell \cdot F = \int_M dA \cdot (\nabla \times F)$$